# Print server side text file at client printer in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net

I do have an asp.net web application, from which I need to display some coupon details in the screen, with the print option on the page.  On clicking the print button, server side formatted text file should be generated and it should be printed in the client local machine.
How to implement this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript

```
window.print()
```

[print](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can print asp.net by java script. from blow code.

```
<asp:Button ID="printButton" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

You can find more ways on following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/351577/How-to-print-in-asp-net

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13795/Creating-print-preview-page-dynamically-in-ASP-NET

I hope it will help you.

Comment: This is equivalent to a pin mailer printing application used in secured environment. This should be printed in LPT Port.